# WSL: How to run browser on the windows from command line of the linux system on WSL

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, webassembly, emscripten

I am trying to use WebAssembly and Emscripten on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). Trying `emrun [name].html` to run a sample HTML file from the command line leads to an error:

```
Unable to find browser "firefox"! Check the correctness of the passed --browser=xxx parameter!
```

How can I access to host (windows) browser from the WSL command line on the Linux system (Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can action exe files within Windows from bash natively once you know the path of the exe. Using Chrome as an example:

```
"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/"chrome.exe
```

The exact same thing can be done for Firefox once the path to the exe is known.

Please note the quotes to deal with spaces an opening/closing brackets in Program Files (x86)

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue:  I passed it as the --browser to emrun ` emrun test.html --browser="/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/"chrome.exe`

Answer (score -1):

You need to install Firefox for the wsl...

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow.  A few suggestions for answering in the future.  First, a bit more information is needed - How would you suggest the user install Firefox for WSL?  Second, what version of Windows is needed for your answer to work.  For instance, you can't install Firefox on WSL on Windows 10 without a *lot* of effort (which you should detail in your answer).  Also, as per the other accepted answer, it *wasn't* necessary to install Firefox for WSL.  I would suggest reading the existing answers before adding a new one in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).